# Set HTML div value using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an HTML page with 2 divs (among other things) - "person" and "person-success", in which "person" is visible and "person-success" hidden. When a button in "person" is clicked, the visible div hides and the previously-hidden div "person-success" shows. The code is given below:

```
<div id="person">
    <br><br>
    <div id="counterNum" class="counter-color" l10nID="M_AC_UT_TXT_20"></div>
    <div role="form">
        ...

        <button type="submit" id="addPerson" class="btn btn-success" l10nID="M_LG_BTN_1"></button>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="person-success" class="hide">
    ...
    <p>
        <span l10nID='M_AC_UT_TXT_19'></span>
        You can add <span id="limit"></span> more people. <a href='<?php echo $root; ?>edituseraccount.php?action=addPerson'>Add another person?</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

The JavaScript:

```
$('#addPerson').click(function() {

    var counter = 0;
    var limit = 10;
    var args = {

    ...

    $.post("addperson.php",args,function(data){  
        var response = JSON.parse(data);    
        if(response.status == 0){
            counter += 1;
            if (counter < limit){
                $('#counterNum').text(counter);
                $('#person').hide();
                $('#limit').text(limit-counter);
                $('#person-success').show();
            }
        }
        console.log(data);      
    });
});
```

Now, when the button is pressed, while "person-success" will show, clicking on "Add another person?" should show "person" and hide "person-success" again. Only this time, the div "counterNum" should be updated with the value of "counter" from the JavaScript. With my code, clicking the link reopens the "person" div and hides the other, but counterNum is not updated, or even shown. Does anyone know how I could do that?

I hope I could explain my problem. Would be grateful for any help!!

Comment: The issue is each time you click on button counter starts from 0, try counter = parseInt($("#counterNum").text, 10) just above the if (counter < limit)

Comment: Your button type is `submit`, didn't is submit the whole page and then reload?

Comment: Also note that `submit` is the default `type` for `button`, so you don't need to specify it if that's what you want.

Comment: And if your PHP page correctly reports the `Content-Type` of what it's sending back, you won't need `JSON.parse` -- jQuery will see the content type and parse it for you.

Comment: T.J Crowder  +1, for adding such an useful information

Answer (score 1):

**Var counter** Make it as global. Because each time when you click on the  addPerson button when counter resets to zero.

```
var counter = 0;
var limit = 10;

$('#addPerson').click(function() {

    var args = {

    ...

    $.post("addperson.php",args,function(data){  
        var response = JSON.parse(data);    
        if(response.status == 0){
            counter += 1;
            if (counter < limit){
                $('#counterNum').text(counter);
                $('#person').hide();
                $('#limit').text(limit-counter);
                $('#person-success').show();
            }
        }
        console.log(data);      
    });
});
```

Comment: Nitpick: Don't make it *global*. Just put it in a scope outside the click handler. Globals are a Bad Thing(tm).

Answer (score 0):

The variable you declare is local scope. 
Declare variable globally outside the click event called.
On each click it resets counter to 0.

Hope it helps !!!